# how to upload a file xlsx, update it and make it available to download in frontend

Tags: node.js, upload, backend

guys

A different question than the others that I used to do here.

My application is a website based on Nuxt/Vuejs (frontend framework), expresse/nodejs for a backend and mongoDB for database NoSQL;

I need to add a space where I can input a file xlsx format in the frontend, make some scripts and modification with the content inside it (with python if it possibly) and then make it available to download a new file xlsx with all the modifications made;

So, someone knows how it is the best way to build it? I need to send the file to the backend, right? Or do I need to send to database to?

I have also the option to add some a backend framework
(django/flask), but I do not know if with nodejs I can solve this problem well.

I am a bit new developping ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it all with [this xlsx library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

You can do it entirely on client side.

Or upload the file to server, do whatever you want (with this library, with python, or anything else), and send back the file when you done.

No database is required.